# How do you get self-signed certificates working for server to server communications?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have software that connects two applications - one that runs on Windows Server 2008 and another that runs on Linux/CentOS.  The Windows app runs within IIS and ASP.NET.  The Linux/CentOS app runs within Apache and Tomcat.  These are web-based apps and they need to talk to each other in a sever-to-server fashion over HTTPS.

I know that if I use a Certificate Authority (CA) for the SSL certificates, then there tends to be no problem getting this communication to work.  I also know that if I use self-signed certificates - or don't use a CA - then I tend to have problems.

Is there a way to get Apache/Tomcat to trust a self-signed cert used by IIS/ASP.NET and visa-versa?  What are the steps to do this?

Are there tools out there that could be used to verify that this has been set up properly?  I assume that running a browser on one server and hitting the other server is not a sufficient test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of setting up self-signed certificates properly, because self-signed certificates have no role in proper SSL communication.

Set up your own CA and you'll be good to go. If your Windows server doesn't already have a built-in CA, there are many documents out there about this. As a starting point, you could use the [EasyRSA CA](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/77-rsa-key-management.html) that is included with OpenVPN.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I just don't understand all of the options.  I know about public or well-known CAs (e.g., Verisign) and I know you can set up your own internal CA (what you are talking about).  I guess the lines blurred for me between self-signed certs and internal CA's.  How do I ensure that servers trust internal CAs?  Keep in mind that I am dealing with different platforms (Windows and Linux).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the right answer, but I have re-worded my question as two new questions: http://serverfault.com/questions/200778/how-do-you-configure-iis-to-trust-internal-certificate-authorities-for-server-to and http://serverfault.com/questions/200789/how-do-you-configure-apache-tomcat-to-trust-internal-certificate-authorities-for