# How do you configure IIS to trust internal Certificate Authorities for server-to-server https requests

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate-authority

I need to perform web service calls from within my own web server running on IIS.  IIS needs to make calls out to another non-Microsoft (Linux) server over HTTPS that uses an internal Certificate Authority (CA) for SSL.

How do I get IIS to trust the proper root certificate from this CA?

Also, how do I test that this trust is working?  I assume a browser request from the server hosting IIS is insufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the certificate from the CA on the server running IIS, and make sure it ends up in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store for the machine.  You may have to open a certificates console in MMC.

Comment: +1. This is not something you do in IIS - trust is a per machine thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Any ideas on how I can verify this setup?  We travel to our clients and install software which relies on this, but want some verification before we go out there.

Comment: If you open the certificate on the server, you can see if it is valid, and you can verify trust up the chain.

Comment: OK, I'll assume that "open the certificate on the server" simply means to use the Certificate MMC snap-in.  Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure to choose Computer Account when opening the certificates snap-in and the import the certificate into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder.

Comment: Nope.  I installed the CA into trusted roots (shows up in certlm), and even though the machine trusts it and it's children, IIS still gives this exact message -- won't even pass the certificate to the web app.