# How do you configure Apache/Tomcat to trust internal Certificate Authorities for server-to-server https requests

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, certificate-authority

I need to perform web service calls from within my own web server running on Apache/Tomcat. Apache/Tomcat running on Linux needs to make calls out to a Microsoft server running IIS over HTTPS that uses an internal Certificate Authority (CA) for SSL.

How do I get Apache/Tomcat to trust the proper root certificate from this CA?

Also, how do I test that this trust is working? I assume a browser request from the server hosting Apache/Tomcat is insufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that you have already exported the CA certificate to a file, such as "internal-ca.pem". Also, I assume that it is Tomcat who initiates the SSL connection to the IIS server.

You <strike>can</strike> must use the Java keytool to import the certificate into the Java keystore that is being used by your Tomcat engine. The keystore for CA certs is $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts. So to import your new internal-ca.pem certificate into this keystore, you would use:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -importcert \
  -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
  -file /path/to/internal-ca.pem  \
  -trustcacerts -alias internal-ca-1
```

The default password for the keystore is: **changeit**

Verify that your cert is in the keystore:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list \
  -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -v | less
```

Test the connection to the server:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /path/to/internal-ca.pem -connect server:port
```

This should give you, near the end of its output:

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

If you want to test the trust from within Tomcat, you will have to write some test code to do it. Sorry, I don't know any Java. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/internal-ca.crt
SSLProxyVerify require
```

Comment: Wait, my solution is for Apache HTTPD, did you mean Apache Tomcat, or Apache HTTPD OR/AND Tomcat?

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Unfortunately, I suspect that it will vary from client to client since this is a product that can be set up in various ways.  My question may have been misleading as my expertise is on the Microsoft/IIS side and not on the Apache/Tomcat (esp. when on Linux as is the case here).  Would you be able to enumerate the options (maybe you already have)?  Of course giving answers for each would be very helpful.  Also, are you saying that the "SSLProxyVerify require" is a verification step?

Comment: It's part of my configuration. Makes problems with the certificate a hard failure instead of a soft one. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html